# Get the focal length from hikvisionapi

Tags: python, hikvision

I'm working with hikvisionapi and I need to get the focal length value, how can I do this?

I looked through all the documentation and couldn't find the corresponding method.

I tried this methods:

```
api.PTZCtrl.channels[1].status
api.System.Video.inputs.channels[1]
```